# Open Joomla "Read More" link under new menu

Tags: joomla, menu, blogs, joomla-article

I'm working on a website that has a Blog Layout at the bottom of the home page, beneath a lot of Web 2.0 style explanatory text.  Currently when I click the article title or "Read More" on any of the home articles, the page is refreshed and the full article information is rendered using the same menu.  The user has to scroll down quite a bit to read the ifno.

Is there any way to have the title/Read More link open under a different menu from which it was called?  Ideally I'd like articles/read more links on my "home" menu to open under my "news" menu..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

call your article "subject-part-1" and create another article called "subject-part-2"
and at the end of "part-1" put a link to "part-2" that says something like "read more..."